# jQuery scripts breaking each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a movie website for my UI/UX class but seem to have some broken scripts. I don't know the best way to format this, since I have multiple scripts,

I first put in CircleType.js to make the "BUDAPEST" arch like on the movie posters. That was all good and fine until I also put a [jQuery tools overlay](http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/overlay/external.html) so that when you click on the "WATCH THE TRAILER" it overlays the background and opens an external link while in that window. I entered that in but it makes the text "BUDAPEST" not arch.

For background, I am pretty solid in HTML and CSS but pretty new to Javascript and jQuery. There is probably something small I'm doing wrong but I just don't have the knowledge to see it. Let me know if you have any questions, and thank you for any help in advance.

```js
<script language="javascript">
    $(function() {

      // if the function argument is given to overlay,
      // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
      $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'black',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

          // grab wrapper element inside content
          var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

          // load the page specified in the trigger
          wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
```

```css
/*****************CSS RESET*********/
header, body, div, blockquote, pre, a, em, small, strong, b, i, u, center, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, li, ul, dl, dt, dd {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-style: normal;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Copse', serif;
}


/*****************BACKGROUND**********/
body {
    background-color: #575964;
    height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

 #overlay {
    background-image: url(overlay.png);
    color: #efefef;
    height: 450px;
  }
  
  /* container for external content. uses vertical scrollbar, if needed */
div.contentWrap {
    height: 441px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/*****************TITLE*************/
h2, h3 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffda85;
 font-family: 'Halant', serif;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 300;
}

h2.grand {
 margin-top: -20px;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h3.the {
 margin-top: 60px;
}

h3.hotel {
 margin: -50px 0 0 0;
}

#circle { 
 font-family: 'Halant', serif;
 font-size: 80px; 
 margin: -50px 0 0 0;
 font-weight: 300; 
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffda85;
}

/****************BUTTONS***************/
div.container{
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

div#left {
 width: 600px;
 margin-top: 120px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 float: left;
}
 
div#right {
 margin-left: 600px;
 margin-right: 100px;
 margin-top: -40px;
 float: right;
}

div.clear {
 clear: both;
}

button {
 font-family: 'Copse', serif;
 background-color: Transparent;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 outline: none;
 padding: 15px 90px;
 font-size: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 text-align: center;

}

a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 padding: 19px 0 16px 0;
 font-weight: 600;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Copse|Halant:300, 400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>GRAND BUDAPEST HOTEL</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="circletype.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
  <h3 class="the">THE</h3><br>
  <h2 class="grand">GRAND</h2><br>

  <div id="circle">BUDAPEST</div>
  <script>
    $('#circle').circleType({
      radius: 384
    });
  </script>

  <h3 class="hotel">HOTEL</h3><br>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">
      <a href="external-content.htm" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none">
        <button type="button">MEET THE CAST</button>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
      <a href="trailer.htm" rel="#overlay" style="text-decoration:none">
        <button type="button">WATCH THE TRAILER</button>
      </a>

      <!-- overlayed element -->
      <div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
        <div class="contentWrap"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function () { // Your Code }
That's the first thing I see that looks weird. You're overcomplicating things.

The second part, NEVER put a button inside a link. They both take inputs, will create wonky and inconsistent behavior across browsers.

What is the function of your <a> links? As in why do you have them there? For looks? Use <div> instead if it's just for looks. Any functionality they implement (any function to be run) should be run by the button.

Comment: @SimonHyll The <a>/<button> combo was copied from the code the overlay gave me. Can I still use the button to open an external video (like from Youtube)? Or can I do the same thing but just use an <a> instead of <button? I've never used the button tag before, just made buttons from <a> tags so I was also wondering why the jQuery code wanted me to use it as well. I'm so inexperienced with jQuery I didn't want to screw anything up but it sounds like it's pretty janky lol

Comment: The button element is primarily used for forms, the big difference is that <a> shows the link destination in the lower left corner of your window while <button> doesn't. Also, <a> should have a href that links to another page, while buttons should have an onclick function that triggers some form of javascript function.

One reason for it not functioning could be that as you press the button it also triggers the link which would trigger an update or redirect from the current page. Your page isn't broken because of jQuery, it's broken because it's poorly constructed (no offense).

Comment: Ignore that .overlay is not a function part, it is a jQuery function since you're loading the appropriate library for it.

Answer (score -1):

Start by making these changes:

```js
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      // if the function argument is given to overlay,
      // it is assumed to be the onBeforeLoad event listener
      $("a[rel]").overlay({

        mask: 'black',
        effect: 'apple',

        onBeforeLoad: function() {

          // grab wrapper element inside content
          var wrap = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap");

          // load the page specified in the trigger
          wrap.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
```

```css
/*****************CSS RESET*********/
header, body, div, blockquote, pre, a, em, small, strong, b, i, u, center, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, li, ul, dl, dt, dd {
 font-size: 11px;
 font-style: normal;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Copse', serif;
}


/*****************BACKGROUND**********/
body {
    background-color: #575964;
    height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

 #overlay {
    background-image: url(overlay.png);
    color: #efefef;
    height: 450px;
  }
  
  /* container for external content. uses vertical scrollbar, if needed */
div.contentWrap {
    height: 441px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

/*****************TITLE*************/
h2, h3 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffda85;
 font-family: 'Halant', serif;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: 300;
}

h2.grand {
 margin-top: -20px;
}

h3 {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h3.the {
 margin-top: 60px;
}

h3.hotel {
 margin: -50px 0 0 0;
}

#circle { 
 font-family: 'Halant', serif;
 font-size: 80px; 
 margin: -50px 0 0 0;
 font-weight: 300; 
 text-align: center;
 color: #ffda85;
}

/****************BUTTONS***************/
div.container{
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 50px;
}

div#left {
 width: 600px;
 margin-top: 120px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 float: left;
}
 
div#right {
 margin-left: 600px;
 margin-right: 100px;
 margin-top: -40px;
 float: right;
}

div.clear {
 clear: both;
}

button {
 font-family: 'Copse', serif;
 background-color: Transparent;
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 outline: none;
 padding: 15px 90px;
 font-size: 15px;
 letter-spacing: 5px;
 text-align: center;

}

a:hover {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 padding: 19px 0 16px 0;
 font-weight: 600;
}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Copse|Halant:300, 400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>GRAND BUDAPEST HOTEL</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="circletype.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<body>
  <h3 class="the">THE</h3><br>
  <h2 class="grand">GRAND</h2><br>

  <div id="circle">BUDAPEST</div>
  <script>
    $('#circle').circleType({
      radius: 384
    });
    function meetCast() {
        // Meet the cast
    }
    function watchTrailer() {
        // Start the trailer
    }
  </script>

  <h3 class="hotel">HOTEL</h3><br>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        <button type="button" onclick="meetCast()">MEET THE CAST</button>
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <button type="button" onclick="watchTrailer()">WATCH THE TRAILER</button>

      <!-- overlayed element -->
      <div class="apple_overlay" id="overlay">
        <div class="contentWrap"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course there is, the link to the cicletype.min.js is a relative path, your browser can't find it. :P

Comment: The error he's having isn't related to circletype not being a function because on his system his browser finds that script.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with how he's calling circleType or ovarlay. What might be iffy is where the "this" inside his overlay function goes, but both functions are called just as the documentation describes. And I've checked the html itself, while it isn't pretty it is no longer incorrect in my version.

Comment: Please update your answer to be complete or remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your comments to actually point out an issue with my answer or stop complaining. His primary issue is that he's mixing links with buttons without actually knowing what they do. Stop saying he has problems that he doesn't have just because it doesn't work on your browser, remove your comments that confuse him when you tell him e.g. that .overlay is not a jQuery function, of course it is, you're just not loading the library that adds it to jQuery.

Comment: im not complaining, your answer is incomplete and I've reflected that in a down vote on your answer.

Comment: @SimonHyll Thank you for all your assistance. I'll work on it a little bit more! I'm a graphic designer by trade and am pretty novice on the accurate semantics of code, as I'm mostly self taught. Once again, thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)